# Android - create and compile project from command line

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

For a project I'm working on, I need to be able to create an android project and then compile it from command line (windows and mac).

I've installed Android Studio + Android SDK on my windows machine and I searched and found that there should be a command `android create project [options]`. But when I run it, first there is no `create project` option, and second, it tells me that `android` command is deprecated and I should use `sdkmanager` instead - but I cannot find any way to create a project from command line using `sdkmanager` and then compile it.

How and can it be done from command line?

Comment: Did you set the **path**?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Comment: This helped me : https://www.hanshq.net/command-line-android.html

Answer (score -3):

You can execute all the build tasks available to your Android project using the Gradle wrapper command line tool. It's available as a batch file for Windows (gradlew.bat) and a shell script for Linux and Mac (gradlew.sh), and it's accessible from the root of each project you create with Android Studio.

To run a task with the wrapper, use one of the following commands:

On Windows:

```
   gradlew task-name
```

On Mac or Linux:

```
  ./gradlew task-name
```

To see a list of all available build tasks for your project, execute tasks:

```
   gradlew tasks
```

**Build a debug APK**

For immediate app testing and debugging, you can build a debug APK. The debug APK is signed with a debug key provided by the SDK tools and allows debugging through adb.

To build a debug APK, open a command line and navigate to the root of your project directory—from Android Studio, select View > Tool Windows > Terminal. To initiate a debug build, invoke the assembleDebug task:

```
   gradlew assembleDebug
```

This creates an APK named module_name-debug.apk in project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/. The file is already signed with the debug key and aligned with zipalign, so you can immediately install it on a device.

Or to build the APK and immediately install it on a running emulator or connected device, instead invoke installDebug:

```
   gradlew installDebug
```

The "Debug" part in the above task names is just a camel-case version of the build variant name, so it can be replaced with whichever build variant you want to assemble or install. For example, if you have a "demo" product flavor, then you can build the debug version with the assembleDemoDebug task.

To see all the build and install tasks available for each variant (including uninstall tasks), run the tasks task.

Run your app on the emulator
To use the Android Emulator, you must create an Android Virtual Device (AVD) using Android Studio.

Once you have an AVD, start the Android Emulator and install your app as follows:

In a command line, navigate to **android_sdk/tools/** and start the emulator by specifying your AVD:

```
  emulator -avd avd_name
```

If you're unsure of the AVD name, execute `emulator -list-avds`.
Now you can install your app using either the Gradle install tasks mentioned above or the adb tool:

```
  adb install path/to/your_app.apk
```

All built APKs are saved in **project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/**.

**Run your app on a device**

Before you can run your app on a device, you must enable USB debugging on your device. You can find the option under Settings > Developer options.

Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Once your device is set up and connected via USB, you can install your app using either the Gradle install tasks mentioned above or the adb tool:

```
   adb -d install path/to/your_app.apk
```

All built APKs are saved in **project_name/module_name/build/outputs/apk/**.

Comment: What you wrote is about compiling an existing application using gradle. How do I create a project from command line to compile?

Comment: Did you checked `android create project -h` for help?

Comment: As I wrote in original post - android command returns a message that it is deprecated...

Comment: so check this out.. https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-android-command-deprecated-error-unable-to-list-target-platforms.458814/ it seems that downgrading the tools fixes the problem

Comment: I don't think the solution should be using something that old rather than understanding how the newer one works :)